# Trigger jquery click on element based on data attribute with array

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a map using svg elements and I want to trigger a click event on certain elements which map to anchors on the page.

Within the element click event I have this line of code (which currently doesn't work).

```
        $('*[data-info="{\"name\":\"' + data.name + '\"}"]').trigger("click");
```

I have seen examples on here on how to select elements based on data attributes but not with the attribute containing an array.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of faking events, extract the logic under those events to their own functions and call that function directly.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the corresponding HTML.

Comment: Show some html will be great..